# Use Identity Aware Proxy to tunnel to a TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

Can I use google cloud's identity aware proxy to connect to the gRPC endpoint on a TPU worker? By "TPU worker" I mean that I am creating a TPU with no associated compute instance (using `gcloud compute tpus create`) and I wish to connect to the gRPC endpoint found by running `gcloud compute tpus describe my-tpu`:

```yaml
ipAddress: <XXX>
port: <YYY>
```

I can easily set up an SSH tunnel to connect to this endpoint from my local machine but I would like to use IAP to create that tunnel instead. I have tried the following:

```sh
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel my-tpu 8470
```

but I get

```
 - The resource 'projects/.../zones/.../instances/my-tpu' was not found
```

This makes sense because a TPU is a not a compute instance, and the command `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel` expects an instance name.

Is there any way to use IAP to tunnel to an arbitrary internal IP address? Or more generally, is there any other way that I can use IAP to create a tunnel to my TPU worker?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done using the internal ip address of the TPU Worker, here is an example:

```
gcloud alpha compute start-iap-tunnel \
  10.164.0.2 8470 \
  --local-host-port="localhost:$LOCAL_PORT" \
  --region $REGION \
  --network $SUBNET \
  --project $PROJECT
```

Be aware that [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access) must be enabled in the TPU subnet, which can be easily done with the following command:

```
gcloud compute networks subnets update $SUBNET \
--region=$REGION \
--enable-private-ip-google-access
```

Just as a reference, here you have an example on how to create a TPU Worker with no external ip address:

```
gcloud alpha compute tpus tpu-vm create \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --zone $ZONE \
  --internal-ips \
  --version tpu-vm-tf-2.6.0 \
  --accelerator-type v2-8 \
  --network $SUBNET \
   $NAME
```

---

AUTHENTICATION

To successfully authenticate the endpoint source of the IAP tunnel, you need to add the SSH keys to the project's metadata following these steps:

1. Check if you already have SSH keys generated in your endpoint:

```
ls -1 ~/.ssh/*

#=>

/. . ./id_rsa
/. . ./id_rsa.pub
```

If you don't have any, you can generate them with the command: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C id_rsa`.

2. Add the SSH keys to your project's metadata:

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
--metadata ssh-keys="$(gcloud compute project-info describe \
--format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))")
$(whoami):$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"

#=>

Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME].
```

3. Assign the iap.tunnelResourceAccessor role to the user:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GCP_PROJECT_NAME \
    --member=user:$USER_ID \
    --role=roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor
```

Comment: Hmm when I run `gcloud alpha compute start-iap-tunnel 10.70.239.74 8470 --local-host-port localhost:19870 --region us-central1 --network default` I get `ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.compute.start-iap-tunnel) While checking if a connection can be made: Error while connecting [4033: 'not authorized'].` Perhaps I need to enable the Tunnel User IAM role on the TPU but I don't know how to do that as there is no info panel on the TPU page on the console.

Comment: @AlexFlint, just edited the answer, added the authentication part